# Facebook web app logout - constants checks to facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok, so i have created a facebook login for a website.

The site has a user account overlay. When the user has a std account the user checks are simple as i am querying my own server. Each page load I run 'isUserLoggedIn()'..

However, if the user logs in with facebook.. things get a little different.

What if the user logs out of facebook? Am i expected to logout the user from my website? If so this would require a call to facebook each and everytime a page was loaded.. what ahve other people done with scenarios like this?

I was thinking that I could check every tenth server request to see if the user is still logged in with facebook?

Or do people not bother and only log the user out of their site when the user specifically logs out of the website?

Comment: In doing a facebook check every page load has increased the load time by an average of half a second.

Comment: and the better way is to check at the client end not your server..